# In ANSI C, how to handle > or < time expressions crossing midnight without using a day variable

Tags: c, algorithm, time, embedded

In the following code example (which compiles and runs):

```
typedef struct BASIC_TIME {
    int hh;
    int mm;
    int ss;
} BasicTime_t;

typedef struct DEVICE {
    // id, settings, etc
    BasicTime_t last_checked;
    BasicTime_t check_interval;
} Device_t;

BasicTime_t GetTimeNow(void) {
    BasicTime_t now;
    // Code to get real-time - differs from platform to platform
    // Edge case for this example:
        now.hh = 23;
        now.mm = 55;
        now.ss = 00;
    return now;
}

int TimeGrEq(BasicTime_t a, BasicTime_t b) {
    // is time a >= time b (i.e. is a later than b) ?
    // Question - is there a more elegant way to write this function?
    if (a.hh < b.hh) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (a.hh > b.hh) {
        return 1;
    } else { // must be same hour
        if (a.mm > b.mm) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.mm < b.mm) {
            return 0;
        } else { //must be same minute
            if (a.ss > b.ss) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a.ss < b.ss) {
                return 0;
            } else { // must be the same time!
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


BasicTime_t AddTime (BasicTime_t t1, BasicTime_t t2) {
    BasicTime_t result;
    // Question is there an elegant way to do this?
    result.hh = t1.hh + t2.hh;
    result.mm = t1.mm + t2.mm;
    result.ss = t1.ss + t2.ss;
    if (result.ss >= 60) {
        result.ss = result.ss % 60;
        result.mm++;
    }
    if (result.mm >= 60) {
        result.mm = result.mm % 60;
        result.hh++;
    }
    if (result.hh >= 24) {
        result.hh = result.hh % 24;
        //We loose any day carry when crossing midnight
        //unless we add another variable

    }
    return result;
}

void ReadDevice(Device_t device) {
    //code to read and log data from the device -
    //e.g. a temperature sensor
    device.last_checked = GetTimeNow();
    printf("Device Checked - Next Should be 10 Minutes From Now\n");
}

int IsItTime(BasicTime_t last_checked, BasicTime_t interval) {
    BasicTime_t now = GetTimeNow();
    BasicTime_t next = AddTime(last_checked, interval);
    if (TimeGrEq(now, next)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    Device_t sensor;

    // to illustrate an edge case example:
    sensor.last_checked.hh = 23;
    sensor.last_checked.mm = 53;
    sensor.last_checked.ss = 0;

    sensor.check_interval.hh = 0;
    sensor.check_interval.mm = 10;
    sensor.check_interval.ss = 0;

    while(1) {
        if (IsItTime(sensor.last_checked, sensor.check_interval)) {
            // In this edge case IsItTime will evaluate TRUE in error
            // Question - In ANSI C is there a smart / best practice
            //      way to detect midnight roll-over in a custom time
            //      struct without extra day flags or variables?
            // Question - How should the test be "debounced" given
            //      that the loop will execute many times during
            //      the 1 second interval (is it possible to do it 
            //      without adding further "done" flags that have to
            //      be cleared later?)

            ReadDevice (sensor);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

1. In ANSI C is there a smart / best practice way to detect midnight roll-over in a custom time struct without extra day flags or variables?
2. Question - How should the test be "debounced" given that the loop will execute many times during the 1 second interval (is it possible to do it without adding further "done" flags that have to be cleared later?
3. How can the time operations code be improved - see inline comments?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157523/discussion-on-question-by-brendanmcl-in-ansi-c-how-to-handle-or-expressions).

Comment: 1. No 2. `time_diff = current_time - previous_time; if (time_diff < 0) time_diff += 24*60*60;` 3. Store timestamps in seconds (or smaller units), only convert to hh:mm:ss or whatever for human-facing output.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that it can only ever cross *one* midnight boundary, using time-of-day only is a bad idea. In fact, it's a bad idea for even only zero or one crossings since, if a job starts 9:15am Monday and finishes 9:30am Tuesday, how many hours is that?

Comment: @paxdiablo : agree. We ended up down this path due the nature of the system (a fodder growing room) prototyped on arduino. The system is off-grid and has no net connectivity, so implementing a proper calendar system (and keeping it synched to real-time) seemed overkill. The user specifies a number of schedule events by setting the days of the week they should run and the start and stop times (or start duration repeat) so at most the system can handle a 1 week repeating timeframe. Needing to run lights and heaters overnight brought up the midnight crossing issue.

Comment: @paxdiablo : in your example the config file would specify start = 09:15:00, stop = 09:30:00, and would be treated as a 15 minute job. Its a limitation of the system therefore that no job can run for more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Definitely use time_t with an epoch reference. As a 32 bit value in seconds from the reference time it allows > < >= and <= expressions to be language native rather than needing special treatment.
2. For a schedule that may start and finish in the same day, or may start today and finish tomorrow (or start yesterday and finish today), and is only described in terms of 24 hour time, there are 6 possible patterns to consider with reference to now : as illustrated and extensively commented in the following code:

.

```
void ScheduleOperate(BlockNode *b) {
    tm* now_tm;
    tm* temp_tm;

    time_t start;
    time_t end;
    time_t zero_today;

    time_t now;
    time_t temp;

    temp = time(NULL);
    temp_tm = localtime(&temp);

    temp_tm->tm_hour = 0;
    temp_tm->tm_min = 0;
    temp_tm->tm_sec = 0;
    zero_today = mktime(temp_tm);

    now = time(NULL);
    now_tm = localtime(&now);


    uint8_t target_state = UINT8_INIT;
    uint8_t today_num = now_tm->tm_wday;
    uint8_t yesterday_num = ((today_num - 1) + 7) % 7;


    switch (b->block_type) {
        case SCH_START_STOP: {

            // convert start and end times to time_t values
            start = zero_today + b->settings.sch.time_start;
            end = zero_today + b->settings.sch.time_end;

            // Determine the pattern - a schedule contained within today (end >= start) or one that
            //  crosses midnight (end < start).

            if (end >= start) { //schedule contained within this 24hr period
                // is today an active day?
                //XXX align day num conversion
                if (b->settings.sch.days[today_num] == 1) {
                    // Could be in 1 of 3 periods
                    //  1 - before start time (start > now && end >= now)
                    //  2 - during the active period (start < now && end >= now)
                    //  3 - after the active period (start < now && end < now)
                    if (start > now && end >= now) target_state = 0;
                    if (start <= now && end > now) target_state = 1;
                    if (start <= now && end < now) target_state = 0;
                }
            } else {
                if (end < start) {
                    //schedule must cross midnight
                    // Could be in 1 of 3 periods
                    //  1 - yesterday was active and it started yesterday and is still running
                    //  2 - if it was active yesterday it is now finished, and not yet time to start again
                    //  3 - in the next active period that will continue past the next midnight

                    // was yesterday an active day? (ie. active period started yesterday)
                    if (b->settings.sch.days[yesterday_num] == 1) {
                        // start an active period from yesterday that should be still running
                        if (start >= now && end > now) target_state = 1;
                        // time to turn it off?
                        if (start >= now && end < now) target_state = 0;
                    }
                    // is today active?
                    if (b->settings.sch.days[today_num]) {
                        if (start <= now && end < now) target_state = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
                if (target_state == 1 && b->active == 0) {              //all conditions met, go active
                    b->active = 1;
                    b->last_update = now;
                    EventMsg(b->block_id, E_ACT);
                }
                if (target_state == 0 && b->active == 1) { //deact
                    b->active = 0;
                    b->last_update = now;
                    EventMsg(b->block_id, E_DEACT);
                }

            break;
        }
```